# Machine Learning algorithm to update values

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I have a list of descriptions from which I have to understand the category and give the input in separate column. Over a period of time I have created a list of keywords which if present in a description would lead to a certain category. Which machine learning algorithm should I use which reads the keywords and update the category automatically? Also it learns over time .

Comment: I would do more research on Natural Language Processing and Text Classification. Here's a link to get you started: https://medium.com/@theflyingmantis/text-classification-in-nlp-naive-bayes-a606bf419f8c

Answer (score 1):

If you want to classify a document based on specific keywords you don't need Machine Learning. There is no learning process involved. If you're looking for a model that can learn the correlation between specific words and their category, you have a few options.

Something easy to start with would be TF-IDF + Logistic Regression. In short, TF-IDF will rate words based on how distinctive they are for a document. A logistic regression will use this resulting information to learn to classify the documents.

A more advanced approach that may also need more data would be a neural network. [Here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn.py) is a simple implementation of the IMDB sentiment analysis (binary classification) using Keras. You will find other architectures like LSTM or FastText in this repo as well.